# como traer datos de una sub referencia mediante metodo populate en mongoose

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose

hola gente estoy haciendo una sala de chat, este es mi modelo de usuario,

```
const Usuario = new Schema({
  nombre: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  apellido: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  socket: {
    type: String
  },
  usuario: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
    lowercase: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    lowercase: true,
    trim: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  chats: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'chat'
    }
  ]
},
{
  timestamps: true
});

export default model("usuario", Usuario);
```

y este es mi modelo de chat

```
const Chats = new Schema({
  participantes: [
      {
          type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: 'usuario',
          required: true
      }
  ],
  mensajes: [
      {
          autor: [ { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'usuario' } ],
          mensage: { type: String},
          imagen: [ { type: String } ],
      }
  ]
},
{
  timestamps: true
});

export default model<IMessage>("chat", Chats);
```

los participantes hacen referencia al usuario para traer los datos con un simple `populate`, pero el problema es ese, que no se como traerlos, cuando inicia la aplicacion envio todos los datos del usuario, en el modelo usuario tengo un campo llamado chats, que es el que guarda la id de la sala, de esta manera pido los datos

```
const usuario: IUser | null = await Usuario.findById(_id)
.populate({path: 'chats'})
```

esta consulta me la devuelve como quiero, mostrando las salas

```
chats: [
  {
    participantes: [Array],
    _id: 5ffca77bdec6e2128c53f256,
    mensajes: [],
    createdAt: 2021-01-11T19:31:07.692Z,
    updatedAt: 2021-01-11T19:31:07.692Z,
    __v: 0
  }
],
```

el problema es que tambien quiero obtener los participantes, pero no me los muestra, lo unico que intente fue agregar otro populate

```
const usuario: IUser | null = await Usuario.findById(_id)
.populate({path: 'chats'})
.populate({path: 'participantes'})
```

pero esto no funciono, ayuda

Comment: leí por ahí que lo podría solucionar con un simple `.populate({path: 'chats.participantes'})` pero esto no me funciono

Comment: en la documentación de mongoose en la sección [populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) leí como buscar en múltiples niveles y realice la siguiente búsqueda `.populate({ path: 'chats', populate: { path: 'participantes'} })` pero me sigue apareciendo lo mismo, no me devuelve los datos del campo `participantes`

Comment: Hola @Enzo, podrias agregar el schema de `Usuario` para saber como esta definido. gracias!

Comment: ya edite la pregunta y agregue el modelo de usuario